# Trouble Querying a Database using Ajax and ColdFusion

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I'm having trouble displaying query results using a combination of ColdFusion, Ajax and a form. I'd like for the code to query the database as the user is typing a number, and then display the number it is closest to as the user is typing. Eventually I want to display the description associated with the number as well...that's why that part of the query is there.

Right now my Ajax seems to be working but I'm not displaying any query results. I know I'm overlooking something. Can anyone help?

Query

```
<cfset itemNumber = 'form.useitem'>
<cfquery name="item_results" datasource="inv_usage" username="#session.db_user#" password="#session.db_pass#">
select item_number, item_desc 
from item_desc_list 
where item_number = '#itemNumber#' 
order by convert_to(item_number,'SQL_ASCII')
</cfquery> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#results').html('<p>' + <cfoutput query="item_results">#item_results.item_number#</cfoutput> + '</p>');
</script>
```

Form

```
<form id="usage" name="usage" method="post" action="item_usage2.cfm">
    <div class="bodyTextBold"><br><br>
        Search for Item Number: 
        <input name="useitem" title="Search" value="Search" onfocus="(this.value == 'Search') && (this.value = '')" onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'Search')">
        <div id='results'></div>
        <div id='ajaxWorking'></div>
        <p>Include INVAs? <input type="checkbox" name="invas" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="action" class="inputSubmitr" value="Submit">
        <input type="submit" name="action" class="inputSubmitL" value="Cancel">
    </div>
    <br />
    <p><a href="./index.cfm">Usage Menu</a></p>
    <p><a href="/RepCorner/index.cfm">Main Menu</a></p>
</form>
```

Ajax

```
<script>

    $('#usage').keyup(function(event) {

    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax(url, {
        data: formData,
        type: "POST",
        success : function(response){
            $('#ajaxWorking').html('<p>Working!</p>');
        }
    }).fail(function(jqHXR){
        $('#results').html('<p>Sorry! Something\'s wrong...<br /> Error: ' + jqHXR.statusText + '<br />Please contact IT.</p>');
    });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You're searching for the string `form.useitem` in your database and not a variable. Is that intended? Also use `cfqueryparam`

Comment: Do one thing at a time.  Start by making sure your query returns results when it is run not using ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your ColdFusion page is supposed to return HTML (or whatever data you want).

```
<!--- Always use <cfqueryparam> for parameters in your SQL. No exceptions. --->
<cfquery name="item_results" datasource="inv_usage" username="#session.db_user#" password="#session.db_pass#">
  select item_number, item_desc 
  from item_desc_list 
  where item_number = <cfqueryparam value="#form.useitem#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
  order by convert_to(item_number,'SQL_ASCII')
</cfquery> 

<!--- build your return HTML here --->
<p>
    <cfoutput query="item_results">#item_results.item_number#</cfoutput>
</p>
```

Your HTML is not supposed to contain inline JS. In this case, the "placeholder" functionality is even built into HTML.

```
<form id="usage" name="usage" method="post" action="item_usage2.cfm">
    <div class="bodyTextBold"><br><br>
        <label for="useitem">Search for Item Number:</label>
        <input name="useitem" id="useitem" title="Search" value="Search" placeholder="Search...">
        <div id='results'></div>
        <div id='ajaxWorking'></div>
        <p>Include INVAs? <input type="checkbox" name="invas" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="action" class="inputSubmitr" value="Submit">
        <input type="submit" name="action" class="inputSubmitL" value="Cancel">
    </div>
    <br />
    <p><a href="./index.cfm">Usage Menu</a></p>
    <p><a href="/RepCorner/index.cfm">Main Menu</a></p>
</form>
```

Your JS is supposed to modify the HTML in the Ajax response, in this case with whatever CF has returned.

```
$('#usage').keyup(function (event) {
    $.post(url, $(this).serialize())
        .done(function (response) {
            $('#results').html(response);
            $('#ajaxWorking').html('<p>Working!</p>');
        })
        .fail(function (jqHXR, status, error){
            $('#results').html("<p>Sorry! Something's wrong...<br /> Error: " + status + "<br />Please contact IT.</p>");
        });
});
```